# Computing linear regressions for every possible permutation of matrix columns

Tags: r

I have a (k x n) matrix. I have initially managed to linearly regress (using the lm function) column 1 with each and every other column and extracted only the coefficients.

```
fore.choose <- matrix(0, 1, NCOL(assets))
for(i in seq(1, NCOL(assets), 1))
{

  abc <- lm(assets[,1]~assets[,i])$coefficients
  fore.choose[1,i] <- abc[2:length(abc)]

}
```

The coefficients are placed in the `fore.choose` matrix.

What I now need to do is to linearly regress column 2 with each and every other column, and then column 3 and so on and so forth and extract only the coefficients.

The output will be a square matrix of OLS univariate coefficients. Kind of similar to a correlation matrix, but it is the beta coefficients I am interested in.

```
fore.choose <- matrix(0, 1, NCOL(assets))
```

will initially need to become

```
fore.choose <- matrix(0, NCOL(assets), NCOL(assets))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just compute the coefficients directly from the correlation matrix, using `beta = cor(x,y)*sd(x)/sd(y)`, like this:

```
# set up some sample data
set.seed(1)
d <- matrix(rnorm(50), ncol=5)

# get the coefficients
s <- apply(d, 2, sd)
cor(d)*outer(s, s, "/")
```

You could also use `lsfit` to get the coefficients of one term on all the others at once and then only have one loop to do:

```
sapply(1:ncol(d), function(i) {
  coef(lsfit(d[,i], d))[2,]
})
```

Comment: Yes, if you really like looping.  But why not just compute them directly from the correlation?

Comment: Looping was simply my first thought at deriving an outcome. I am however going follow your suggestion and compute them directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there must be a more elegant way than to nested loops.

```
fore.choose <- matrix(NA, NCOL(assets), NCOL(assets))
abc <- NULL

for(i in seq_len(ncol(assets))){ # loop over "dependant" columns
  for(j in seq_len(ncol(assets))){ # loop over "independant" columns
     abc <- lm(assets[,i]~assets[,j])$coefficients 
     fore.choose[i,j] <- abc[-1]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to how I originally thought I would solve this problem. On the face of it, it seems like it will work, and I think it does, except a problem arises at writing the coefficients into a matrix - the line: `fore.choose[i,j] <- abc[-1]` As I think you know, R will write only the last iteration of a loop, unless manipulated to do otherwise - which was the intention here. For some reason only the final calculated coefficient is shown in the matrix.

Comment: There was a mistake in my code, it should've `seq_len` and not `seq_along`. `-1` meas to write every coeffcient except the intercept. In this case there's only one.